# ASIHttpRequest returning 200 when server connection times out or is cut

Tags: ios, objective-c, asihttprequest

I am using the ASIHttpRequest library for IOS to attempt to download a zip file from my iPad application and it all works fine. However, I am trying to simulate a request timeout and handle this situation appropriately. I am using a trial version of CharlesProxy to attempt to simulate a timeout and Im also killing my tomcat server. In the situation where I am killing the tomcat server in the middle of the zip download, the ASIHttpRequest is still receiving a 200 response, with the error object begin set to nil even though the download is not complete and is not successful. 
I have checked the downloadComplete property on the ASIHttpRequest request object and it is set to YES.

Has anyone else noticed this?

Comment: Be aware that `ASIHttpRequest` is very old, has some known bugs and is no longer maintained by it author. He suggest you move to another library like [`AFNetworking`](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)

Comment: yeah I know. This application Im working on is 4 years old but Im not sure its worth modifying it to use another library. Appreciate your answer though..I will plough on :)